# Insert first rows id into consecutive rows

Tags: sql-server

```
Rid    item    color    Image         parentid
1      810     Black    Images1.jpg   NULL
2      810     Black    Images1b.jpg  2
3      810     Black    Images1c.jpg  3
4      810     pink     Images2.jpg   NULL
5      810     pink     Images2b.jpg  5
6      810     pink     Images2c.jpg  6
```

Above is my @Libtemp table. Now i need to update this table such that records(2,3) must have their parentid as 1 and record (5,6) must have parentid as 4. How do i achieve this?

Comment: You should really try it yourself first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE T SET
       T.parentid = (SELECT MAX(A.rid) 
                     FROM   @Libtemp A 
                     WHERE  A.rid < T.rid AND A.parentid IS NULL) 
FROM   @Libtemp T
WHERE  T.parentid IS NOT NULL
```